# Why can't I create a scheduled task using a domain account?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-task

I don't recall running into this problem before, but I've hit a brick wall today.

I'm trying to create a scheduled task, and I'm using credentials for my domain account, which is also an Administrator account on this local machine, but I keep getting error that says 'access is denied'.

What am I missing here? If the domain account is setup as an admin account on the local machine, shouldn't it be able to fire scheduled tasks?

Comment: Are you try to create the scheduled task and have it execute with your credentials as well? Or will the scheduled task run under a local account?  Are you able to change an existing task to use your credentials?  You mention trying to create the tasks and being able to fire tasks, so it's a little unclear which you're really running into issue with.

Comment: Agent_9191 - I'm not really sure how much clearer I can be than I was above.  I have a domain login to this workstation that I've used daily for years, the domain login is setup as an admin account on this local machine, and I can't manage to setup a scheduled task with these credentials.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to close this, but it seems like it's dead.  

I assumed someone would be able to at least confirm 'Yes, you absolutely should be able to create a scheduled task as an admin-level domain user'.  OR, confirm that this isn't and hasn't been a possibility.

Let me know if I should put the nail in this one and leave it to the great heap of Windows unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that a domain account can get locked out at the domain while still be logged in interactively on a workstation.  This could prevent a scheduled task from being created (amongst a host of other problems with services and various layered products).

Comment: Sounds about right. My advice would be to reboot the machine in question and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have rebooted the workstation - no difference.  Weird stuff, and frustrating.

Comment: @Ducain: what is it that your task will be doing?

Comment: @Sqillman - just starts a little VB.NET app.

Comment: @Ducain is there a UI to it or is it a console app?

Comment: It would help me if I knew what you were aiming at here.  Are you suggesting somehow the app is responsible for the 'access denied' permission problem when creating the scheduled task?  I'm confused...

Comment: @Ducain sorry, haven't been able to get back to this.  I've seen it where a process with a UI will not start or hang in a non-interactive session and was going to look at if this could be related.  I've never seen the actual creation of a task fail because of this, but...

Answer (score 1):

The account must be allowed to run as a Batch Job. [Directions](http://www.brooksnet.com/faq/117-02.html).

Comment: I followed those directions, and actually found that my domain account was already in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you prefixing the domain name and a backslash to your username?
For example: domain-name\username

Comment: Absolutely.  This is a domain account I've used every day for years, and it's an admin account on this local machine.

MYDOMAIN\MyUserName